# Using an ActiveX object from an Outlook hosted webpage - possible?

Tags: scripting, outlook, activex

I'm trying to do the following:

We have an outlook plugin, written in .NET (and C++). It does various things, and is manually installed on the end users machines (usually via AD deployment or similar)

We are changing our search to use a webpage-based search, but from within outlook. That part is ok, however we want to communicate from the webpage to the surrounding outlook application.

We can call into outlook by exposing an ActiveX object from our plugin, however we get security warnings, even if it's signed and marked as safe for scripting.

Is this even possible? Has anyone done it? Anyone have a better way of doing it? We only need to pass in a small amount of data (a message id), and only from the webpage to outlook

[update]: This is the error: automation server can't create object. We can get around it a bit by turning things off in IE, but thats not a good way to do it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going.

http://blogs.msdn.com/e2eblog/archive/2008/01/09/outlook-folder-homepage-hosting-wpf-activex-and-windows-forms-controls.aspx

Marcus